# What is the [drawer] tag for?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

The [drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawer) tag currently has no description, and it's not entirely clear what it's supposed to refer to.

I'd personally be inclined to get rid of it, unless its intended purpose (if there is one) can be sufficiently clarified.

Comment: Usually I've heard of drawers in a UI context, usually with regards to hidden navigation pane. That also appears to be what the first few questions are about at a passing glance.

Comment: As an aside, I'm old enough that one of my first thoughts was the Amiga Workbench interface: https://wiki.amigaos.net/wiki/Using_the_Workbench

Comment: At a skim, [most question ask about drawer and android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawer+android) (37/56 = 66%). I suspect it's [maybe this thing](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout) or, in general, [drawer layouts](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer#usage). The [rest of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawer+-android) do also seem to be about UI. The usage seems quite clear from the usage. Nobody wrote a description but the questions revolve around a single concept.

Comment: Also, if you are proposing burnination, you should really go through [the criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) for that.

Comment: [drawer], (huh, yeah), what is it good for?

Comment: Let's [drawer] flamethrowers at this tag

Comment: Burn the [drawer]?

Comment: @VLAZ maybe it's worth making it a disambiguation request then?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine not sure there is anything to disambiguate - drawer is a common type of UI widget. Like [[tag:accordion]], [[tag:modal-dialog]] or [[tag:slider]]. You can implement those in many ways with different libraries and in different languages but the tags still qualify the concept itself. For non-UI we have [[tag:arrays]] for example which also varies with different languages and yet does describe the same concept in all. The tag seems fine. Or consistent with how other tags similar to it are used. I still don't see a compelling reason to do anything than add a description.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I'd actually forgotten about the tag-disambiguation option, which is more in line with what I was originally trying to get across here, so I've added it now. I'd be happy for the tag to remain, so long as its purpose is clear and unambiguous, which (to me at least) it isn't right now, since a "drawer" as term for a UI concept is honestly not something I've heard used since the Amiga days.

Comment: Should this tag be with[drawer]n?